# Opening new UserControl in MainWindow erases all empty rows

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Once I run the program, it opens a UserControl in my MainWindow. The UserControl is a Menu consisting of 3 buttons.
Image of the UserControl:
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiZfh.png)

The code behind Main Window:

```
<Window 
    ...
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>  //Inserts a UserControl
```

The code behind Menu UserControl:

```
<UserControl 
         ...
         d:DesignHeight="90" d:DesignWidth="525" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>  //Problem
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>  //Problem
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,0" Content="First" Command="{Binding DataContext.SwitchToNextUserControl, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0" Content="Second"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="30,0" Content="Third"/>

</Grid>
```

THE PROBLEM:
Once the menu is opened, the empty rows (those without buttons, first and third) get collapsed (or just height to 0?), as shown: [Running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2YDk.png)
I can get over it with setting MinHeight for every row, but it works only on pixels. I'd like them to work in the method of stars ("*"). I guess I could set their height from code behind (using stars), but just the thought of it makes me feel like I rub my right ear with left hand.

Also, once I click on the "First" button, some other UserControl is opened in the window, instead of the "Menu" one, and its rows are also collapsed. Just mentioning it.

So the question is, what should I do to make my UserControls appear just as they look in designer?

Comment: What's the height of the window and what happens if you increase it?

Comment: The height can be seen on the code I posted, it's 350 on MainWindow, which is being replaced by UserControl's 90 the moment program starts. Nothing changes if I resize them in the code. It always takes the Height of Buttons (according to their FontSize I guess)

Comment: What happens if you resize the window?

Comment: Looks like the moment I click on the bottom border to begin resize, all 3 rows begin resizing according to star(" * ") numbers.

Comment: So your issue is that the height of the window is the same as the height of the Button originally. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` from your window XAML.

This causes the height of the window to shrink to fit the size of the `UserControl` (and effectively the height of the middle `Button`).

Comment: If I remove the SizeToContent part, the MainWindow will always stay its size (350 in Height). I want it to resize according to the UserControl that is currently in use

Comment: Then you should specify a MinHeight for the Grid in the UserControl. You cannot both have the window resize to its content and at the same have the content resize itself to fit the window. This is indeed impossible.

Comment: I don't want the content to resize to fit the window, I just want it to be of a certain size. It works if I specify the height of rows in pixels and not with stars.

Comment: "I don't want the content to resize to fit the window, I just want it to be of a certain size". Then you should set the MinHeight of the Grid in the UserControl as I suggested.

Comment: When I specify a MinHeight, the rows just become that high, without looking at the star values. They just take MinHeight for the regular Height for some whatever reason.

Comment: I mean I could just set their Height instead of MinHeight, it would be the same

Comment: Maybe I'm just being unreasonable though, and ask too much haha.. I'll accept your answer for now, thank you for your time